# Is it possible to have a ride request without authenticating the traveler?

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to use UberAPi to request rides while not requiring an authentication from the end user (rider).
My company should be responsible for the payments from such rides, and would only request that a driver appears at point A at such time, and deliver someone to point B.

Uber business does have all the features needed for such an integration: Usage reports, expense codes, and else, but I see no way of doing this without either an SSO or OAuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to use the api for such a use case. You might want to consider using [Uber Central](http://central.uber.com/).

Comment: Yeah, Uber central turned out to be the answer. An api for it would be awesome, though.